# How to enable the Python program to load and use a few different packages with the same name?

Tags: python, import

I'm developing a Python application that controls hardware. The hardware consists of FPGA-based systems. Their internal structure from the control point of view is managed with an automated system AGWB ( http://github.com/wzab/agwb.git ).

The description of each system is compiled into a Python module "agwb" containing a few submodules.
After the module is loaded, it is used to produce an object handling further communication with the associated system.

When my application works with a few different systems, it has to load a few different "agwb" modules (of course, each one from a different directory).

Loading of the module from a specified directory can be easily achieved by adding that directory at the beginning of the `sys.path` (and removing it, after the module is loaded).

Unfortunately, Python imports the module "agwb" only once. Later attempts to import it results in using of the previously loaded one.
Using the `importlib.reload` also does not help.
After some reading of the https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html I have found the following solution:

```py
import sys
import importlib

def load_agwb(lddir,top):
    sys.path.insert(0,lddir)
    importlib.import_module('agwb')
    # Get the class for the top entity
    res = getattr(sys.modules['agwb'],top)()
    sys.path.remove(lddir)
    sys.modules.pop('agwb')
    mods_to_remove = []
    for mod in sys.modules.keys():
        if mod.find('agwb.') == 0:
            mods_to_remove.append(mod)
    for mod in mods_to_remove:
        sys.modules.pop(mod)
    return res

at1 = load_agwb('./t1','top_v0')
at2 = load_agwb('./t2','top_v0')
print("Call at1.show")
at1.show()
print("Call at2.show")
at2.show()
```

The directories "./t1", and "./t2" contain two different versions of "agwb" module.

After executing the script we get the following output proving that indeed two different versions of "agwb" have been loaded and are used simultaneously:

```
Call at1.show
object from t1, desc= That's version from directory t1
type ID= 1111
Call at2.show
object from t2, desc= That's version from directory t2
type ID= 2222
```

The whole minimal demonstrator is available (as a shar archive) at https://pastebin.com/ZGZj8qV1 (unfortunately, I can't attach a file to my question).

And here come my questions:

- Is the above described method a reliable, legal solution in Python?
- Maybe it works just by chance and may stop working in the next version of Python?
- Are there other, more "official" methods of solving my problem?

Comment: Why not just use `from blabla.folder_1 import agwb as agwb_1` and then `agwb_2`, etc.?

Comment: Yes, your solution also works. At first glance it is more standard. Of course for complex and long paths including the folder may be difficult, but it may be solved by creating the temporary directory with a symlink to the original one. I have yet to investigate if this approach resolves all possible problems. (I can imagine certain difficulties if a temporarily imported "agwb" module has to be accessible strictly via that name in load_agwb. My "minimal demonstrator" may be simply too minimalistic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an answer based on `pavel's` comment (thanks a lot!).
I've used the temporary directory and symlinks to solve the problem of long, and complex paths. Below is the result:

```py
import sys
import os
import importlib
import tempfile

# Directory with description of the first board
dir1 = './xt1/very/long/path'
# Directory with description of the second board
dir2 = './xt2/completely/different/path'

# Name of the top entity in the design
top = 'top_v0'

# Create a temporary directory
tmpdir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()

# Add it to the Python path
sys.path.insert(0,tmpdir.name)

# Create symlinks to the directories with descriptions of the boards
os.symlink(os.path.abspath(dir1),tmpdir.name+"/t1")
os.symlink(os.path.abspath(dir2),tmpdir.name+"/t2")

# Import description of the first board as agwb
import t1.agwb as agwb

# use the imported agwb
at1 = getattr(agwb,top)()
# if the name of the top entity is constant, you can do it easier
bt1 = agwb.top_v0()

# Import description of the second board as agwb
import t2.agwb as agwb

# use the imported agwb
at2 = getattr(agwb,top)()
# if the name of the top entity is constant, you can do it easier
bt2 = agwb.top_v0()

# Now we can remove the temporary directory from the python path
sys.path.remove(tmpdir.name)
# We can even delete it (otherwise it will be deleted when Python session ends)
tmpdir.cleanup()

# Check if both versions are loaded and available
print("Call at1.show")
at1.show()
print("Call at2.show")
at2.show()

print("Call bt1.show")
bt1.show()
print("Call bt2.show")
bt2.show()
```

As previously, the whole `minimal reproducer` is available in the shar format at https://pastebin.com/GrRUh8U9 .

Comment: The above solution may be difficult to apply, if you don't know the number of the boards in advance, and you can't put `t1.agwb`, `t2.agwb` and so on in the code. Then of course you may import it as `agwb = importlib.import_module('t'+str(board_number)+'.agwb')`. Of course the symlinks must be also generated daynamically, based on the board number.